# Observable of a timer never completes despite takeUntil

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm having a lot of pain understanding why my observable never completes.

My code is supposed to work like this :

1. A subject `isTimerEnabled$` initialized to false
2. It is `switchMap`'d to a function that either returns `Rx.Observable.never()` when `isTimerEnabled$` emits false, otherwise it maps to a `Rx.Observable.timer` observable
3. From the timer I `take` everything for 1 second.
4. After 1 second, the observable completes

The issue is that when I subscribe to all of this, my observer's `complete` method is never called.

Here is the code, maybe more helpful :

```js
const isTimerEnabled$ = new Rx.Subject(false).switchMap(
  isTimerEnabled =>
    isTimerEnabled
      ? Rx.Observable
        .timer(0, 100)
        .timeInterval()
        .pluck('interval')
        .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(1000))
      : Rx.Observable.never()
)

isTimerEnabled$.subscribe(
   console.log, 
   console.error, 
   () => console.log('complete !')
)
```

So when I do :

```
isTimerEnabled$.next(true)
```

It logs 10 times to the console, then .. well that's it (I simplified my code snippet for the purpose of .. well simplicity)

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isTimerEnabled$.complete()` and this will complete your Observable stream.

```js
const isTimerEnabled$ = new Rx.Subject(false).switchMap(
  isTimerEnabled =>
    isTimerEnabled
      ? Rx.Observable
        .timer(0, 100)
        .timeInterval()
        .pluck('interval')
        .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(1000))
      : Rx.Observable.never()
)

isTimerEnabled$.subscribe(
   console.log, 
   console.error, 
   () => console.log('complete !')
)

setTimeout(() => isTimerEnabled$.next(true), 1000);
setTimeout(() => isTimerEnabled$.complete(), 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, could you illustrate with a little code snippet ?

Comment: Maybe I was not specific enough on the fact that I wanted my Observable to complete from itself, and not imperatively call complete on the subject.

Comment: There is no way to complete this Observable without Subject being "completed".
It is possible to achieve something similar if you remove Subject and left `isTimerEnabled` as function from `boolean` to `Observable`, then result of that function will complete because of `.takeUntill`.